# Update page contents based on URL and do not reload the whole page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

### Context

I am using ReactRouter 4.

I have the following base Router

```
<Router>
    <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
    <Route
      path="/courses/:courseName"
      render={(props) => {
        switch (props.match.params) { 
          case '1':
            return React.createElement(
              fetch('courses/1/')(CoursePage),
              props,
              null
            );
          case '2':
            return React.createElement(
              fetch('courses/2/')(CoursePage),
              props,
              null
            );
          default:
            return <FourOFour />
        }
      }}
    />
</Router>
```

What `fetch('courses/NUMBER/')(CoursePage)` does, is that it wraps the `CoursePage` component inside a HOC which makes an API request to fetch data relevant to the specific course and when it gets a successful response the `CoursePage` component gets rendered with the data passed as props. In the meanwhile a loading screen is displayed instead.

Now, inside `CoursePage` the way its contents are laid out is based on whether the user is logged in or logged out.

If the user is logged out, the `LoggedOut` component is rendered inside the `CoursePage`'s `render()` method, and they see one page with all content laid continuously in the page.

If the user is logged in, the `LoggedIn` component is rendered inside the `CoursePage`'s `render()` method, and they see the same content as above, but it is now broken into tabbed sections, meaning the user can no longer see the whole content of the page with one scroll, they have to select the appropriate tab in order to see the relevant content.

So, for example, if I was logged out, and hit the page for course 1, I would go to `www.page.com/courses/1` and see a page with 3 sections (Overview, Contents, Reviews) one after the other.

If I was logged in and hit the page for course 1, I would go to `www.page.com/courses/1` and see a page with 3 tabs (Overview, Contents, Reviews) and clicking each tab should display the relevant content.

Now, I got the following requirement:

Each section, when the user is logged in, should reflect on the URL when it's selected. So, if I click on the "Contents" tab, while logged in, the URL should become `www.page.com/courses/1/contents`.

### Problem

I decided to implement this functionality with ReactRouter, so, in the `LoggedIn` component's `render()` method, I made the tabs `NavLink` elements, and I placed the following code:

```
<Router>
  <section>
    <Route
      exact
      path="/courses/:courseName"
      render={(props) => {
        return this.determineVisibleSection('overview', data);
      }}
    />
    <Route
      path="/courses/:courseName/:section"
      render={(props) => {
        return this.determineVisibleSection(props.match.params.section, data);
      }}
    />
  </section>
</Router>
```

`this.determineVisibleSection(sectionName, data)` simply passes the `data` to the appropriate component to render based on the `sectionName` and returns it.

The problem with this, is that when a section is clicked, the **whole** page loads again.

What I mean by that, is that the `fetch('courses/NUMBER/')(CoursePage)` is fired again, and we get the loading screen while we wait for the data to return, and finally the page is displayed with the section that we clicked now selected and the correct content below.

I think I understand why this happens. Since the URL is changed, all `Router` components get notified of the change and so do their `Route` components, so since in the base `Router` the component to render is basically new each time, even if we are on the same page, since a new one is returned by `fetch()()`, the page is "reloaded".

### The question

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour? Meaning, to not have the change to the URL, by the selected section, affect the whole page. Have it only affect the current course page contents.

One way I came up with, that seems to work is the following:

I rewrote my base `Router` like this

```
<Router>
  <Page>
    <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
    <Route path="/courses/:courseName" component={CoursePages} />
  </Page>
</Router>
```

and `CoursePages` is this

```
class CoursePages extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return this.props.match.url !== nextProps.match.url;
  }

  render() {
    switch (this.props.match.url) {
      case '/courses/1':
        return React.createElement(fetch('courses/1/')(CoursePage), this.props, null);
      case '/courses/2':
        return React.createElement(fetch('courses/2/')(CoursePage), this.props, null);
      default:
        return <FourOFour />;
    }
  }
}
```

The key to this whole thing being the `shouldComponentUpdate` and the fact that I have the second `<Router />` in the `LoggedIn` component, since the second `<Router />` will force its contents to re-render even if the parent component does not re-render (because of the `shouldComponentUpdate`)

Is there a better way to do that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think putting the section routes inside the `LoggedIn` component is better. Because it's more react-router v4 way to handle this kind of scenarios (see [this basic example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic) from the documentation).

First, keep your base Router in the first code block as it is. With the given explanation, I assume your CoursePage component is more or less like this.

```
class CoursePage extends Component{

  //...

  render(){
    return this.props.IsLoggedIn ? <LoggedIn/> : <LoggedOut/>
  }
}
```

And now put Routes in your LoggedIn component for different sections as follows.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Switch
  Route,
  Redirect
} from 'react-router-dom'

class LoggedIn extends Component{

  // ...

  render(){
    const { match } = this.props;
    return (
      <Switch>
        {/* This will redirect /courses/:courseName to /courses/:courseName/overview */}
        <Redirect exact from={`${match.url}/`} to={`${match.url}/overview`}/>
        <Route path={`${match.url}/overview`} component={Overview}/>
        <Route path={`${match.url}/contents`} component={Contents}/>
        <Route path={`${match.url}/reviews`} component={Reviews}/>
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}
```

Probably you will need to add more component or HTML tags to this render method to make it looks like tabs with headers.

Since section routes are rendered after CoursePage get rendered, it won't fetch data again when you navigate to different sections in the same course.

Comment: Unfortunately, this still results in data fetching from the server when theURL changes. I think it's because, to quote from my question, "in the base Router the component to render is basically new each time". Also, the <Redirect /> will redirect to `/overview` even if the URL to load was something like `/courses/:coursename/reviews`

Comment: Yeah, just realized that still there is an issue in base Router. But I'm not sure why <Redirect /> doesn't work even with `exact`.